# Как связать Docker Desktop и Intelij?

Tags: spring, docker, linux-mint

Я решил перейти на Linux Mint, установил Docker, запускаю в своей ИДЕИ Dockerfile, но в Docker Desktop ничего не появляется. Через консоль всё работает и я могу запустить какой ни будь gradle из Docker Hub.

[image: screenshot]

Как это пофиксить?

Устанавливал просто скачав DEB package отсюда https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/.

Не знаю поможет это или нет, но вот вывод с дебага, когда запускаю "docker build -t app .". Я использую testcontainers и всё падает на проверке тестов. Код правильный, у моего коллеги всё работает.

```
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.477+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.477+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]       .   ____          _            __ _ _
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.478+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.478+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.478+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.478+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]       '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.478+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.479+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]      :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.479+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.675+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2023-10-18T10:18:21.673Z  INFO 233 --- [ers-lifecycle-0] .t.d.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy : docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([/opt/java/openjdk/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin])
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.677+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2023-10-18T10:18:21.676Z ERROR 233 --- [ers-lifecycle-0] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.681+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.681+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        DockerDesktopClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception NullPointerException (Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.toString()" because the return value of "org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerDesktopClientProviderStrategy.getSocketPath()" is null)As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.682+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     See https://java.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.737+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2023-10-18T10:18:21.727Z ERROR 233 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:791) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.738+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:277) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:268) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:152) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:193) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109) ~[docker-java-api-3.3.3.jar:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:333) ~[testcontainers-1.19.1.jar:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:787) ~[na:na]
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]        ... 4 common frames omitted
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.739+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.741+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
313.5 2023-10-18T10:18:21.741+0000 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] InquiryServiceApplicationTests STANDARD_ERROR
```

Я даже могу сбилдить локально проект используя "gradle build", но опять же ничего не появляется, хотя как минимум Рюк должен был скачатся.

```
dmitry@dmitry-System-Product-Name:/$ gradle build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
8 actionable tasks: 8 up-to-date
dmitry@dmitry-System-Product-Name:/$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
dmitry@dmitry-System-Product-Name:/$
```